# Deserialize a JSON object with support for embedded associations

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

Is there an easy way to deserialize a JSON string to a domain class with support of embedded association; belongsTo and hasMany

```
{
  name: "Customer",
  contact: {
    name: "Contact"
  }
} 

class Customer {
  name 
  Contact contact
}

class Contact {
  String name
  static belongsTo = [customer:Customer]
}
```

in my controller I would like to do the following

```
def save() {
   def customer = new Customer(request.JSON)
   customer.save();
}
```

Now i'm forced to do

```
def save() {
   def contact = new Contact(request.JSON.contact);
   def customer = new Customer(request.JSON);
   customer.contact = contact;
   customer.save();
}
```

Comment: grails.converters.json.default.deep is setted to true?

Comment: So to give you an idea, you have to convert that to : `{
  name: "Customer",
  contact.name: "Contact"
}`

Comment: grails.converters.json.default.deep is not set at all, and doesn't make any difference when i set it to true in config.groovy

Comment: @JamesKleeh Geee if that's true, then that's really counter-intuitive. It should rather be handled internally when parsing the JSON.

Comment: Well the data binding is for setting data from an html form, not from a JSON, so it is not designed to take objects because it doesn't make any sense to do so on a form.

Comment: data binding should be agnostic to the payload type.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using Ember.js?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JsonSlurper?

Example usage:

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText('{"person":{"name":"Guillaume","age":33,"pets":["dog","cat"]}}')

assert result.person.name == "Guillaume"
assert result.person.age == 33
assert result.person.pets.size() == 2
assert result.person.pets[0] == "dog"
assert result.person.pets[1] == "cat"
```

Ref: http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html

you can try this

```
    Test test
    def result = new JsonSlurper().parseTest('yourString')
    test = result
```

Try this will work.